# How to make a url params from array data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I can get some data like below:

```
data = ["s=abc","t=123","a=567","b=789"]
```

How I can handle these data to obtain a url string like "?s=abc&t=123&a=567&b=789"

I write some code

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  data[i].split("=");
}
```

but stuck for a while.

Can anyone help me?
by the way, the data.length may different each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How I can handle these data to obtain a url string like `"?s=abc&t=123&a=567&b=789"`

Use `join` with `&` as glue. This will concat the elements of the array by using `&` as glue, then you can prepend `?` to the resulting string.

```js
var data = ["s=abc", "t=123", "a=567", "b=789"];
var params = '?' + data.join('&');

console.log(params);
document.write(params);
```

**Note:** If your parameters contains special characters you can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the params to be url encoded, use `$.param( data);`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Answer (score 1):

You can just use join function. it converts arrays into strings then add the & as a delimiter then concatenate "?";

```
var new_data = '?'+data.join('&');
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your data array and concatenate ampersand `'&'` with each element and remove last `'&'` using `slice`.

```
data = ["s=abc","t=123","a=567","b=789"];
    link="?";
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      link+=data[i]+"&";
    }
    link=link.slice(0,-1);
    console.log(link);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode the value - if the values not already encoded

```js
data = ["s=abc", "t=123", "a=567", "b=7 89"]
var params = data.map(function(item) {
  return item.replace(/=(.*)/, function(m, value) {
    return '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)
  })
}).join('&');
snippet.log(params)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hash for the key/value pairs and leverage jQuery to serialize the params into a string you can use.

```
var serializedParams = {
  s: 'abc',
  t: '123',
  a: '567',
  b: '789'
};

$.param(serializedParams);

// Returns:
// s=abc&t=123&a=567&b=789
```

or you can just manually construct the string yourself.

```
var data = ["s=abc","t=123","a=567","b=789"];

data.join('&');

// Returns:
// s=abc&t=123&a=567&b=789
```